# What 3d shape has only 1 side?

Tags: geometry

There are many 3d figures, but can you figure out what 3d figure (with a completely flat surface) has only 1 side?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "with completely flat surfaces"?  Why do you use the plural (surfaces) for a figure that has only one side — what's the distinction?

Comment: A single-track audio tape cassette (which doesn't have a Side B).  :)

Comment: If you are wondering why this question is garnering downvotes, it is because this is really just a trivia question, where the answer is even fairly common knowledge. This does not really fit on this site as the purpose is to create puzzles. In the future try to refrain from asking questions such as this one to avoid downvotes

Comment: @KeyboardWielder I'm sorry, but this is geometric stuff, and CDs aren't completely flat.

Comment: I think what OP means by "completely flat surface" is that the figure has no volume, not that it's 2-dimensional.

Comment: @Xxoplechic: My answer was more of a joke (punning on "side"), that's why I posted it as a comment.  :) BTW, I was referring to a cassette which was basically like a box with 2 spools of magnetic tape inside.  Far from flat, but then I still don't get how something as twisted as a mobius strip is flat either.  :P

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's plain trivia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems a bit too easy but is it:

> A [Möbius strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip)

Comment: That has two sides doesn't it?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil:  No, it doesn't.  But if it qualifies as having "completely flat surfaces", I don't understand what the OP means by those words.

Comment: @PeregrineRook I assume that was to rule out a solid sphere

Comment: Yeah it depends on what he means by completely flat surfaces. Honestly I hope there is a more interesting answer than this

Comment: @PeregrineRook If it had any thickness that would mean it technically has 2 or more sides.

Answer (score 3):

> A Klein Bottle [(wikipedia article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle)
>
>  [image]

Comment: Yes, that works! I forgot about that (I read it in a book).

Comment: That was my first thought when I saw Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's anything like an actual 3D shape

Is it

> Your shadow

Comment: No, that is 2d.

Comment: There is a 3d surface for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A [gömböc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6mb%C3%B6c)? (It's a 3-d shape which has only one stable point of equilibrium.)

Comment: I'm sorry, that probably is right, but I need to understand what a gömböc is   before I can see. Right now I mean a Möbius strip.

Comment: The link I supplied in my answer links to a page which has a picture of one.

Comment: Good! That works too!